# Transferring ownership of business page on facebook

Tags: facebook, instagram, meta-business-suite

I have just taken over a business and the previous owner is trying to transfer over ownership of the business page with no luck.
She has successfully added me as admin but when following the steps to transfer ownership she gets to the point of searching for me but my name does not come up ?
Can anyone help ?